# Error testing insert functionality in test class

Tags: java

I created a project using quarkus framework from an api-rest. I started creating test classes for the project. The database for the tests is the H2 database. The first class to be tested is the "user" entity controller class (UserResourceTest.java); in the method to test the functionality of inserting a "user" record I am getting an HttpStatus 500 error. Here is information from the log with the error:

```
2023-05-07 20:49:12,808 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, hibernate-orm, hibernate-orm-panache, hibernate-validator, jdbc-h2, jdbc-postgresql, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jsonb, smallrye-context-propagation, vertx]
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        users
        (id, age, name) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?)
2023-05-07 20:50:32,376 WARN  [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-0) SQL Error: 42104, SQLState: 42S04
2023-05-07 20:50:32,377 ERROR [org.hib.eng.jdb.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (executor-thread-0) Table "USERS" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into users (id, age, name) values (default, ?, ?) [42104-214]
2023-05-07 20:50:32,407 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) HTTP Request to /users failed, error id: 423df137-a754-4500-be57-0012d85d487c-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
```

Below is the configuration of the application.properties and the classes to be analyzed.

application.properties

```
#GLOBAL
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=root123

quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/quarkus-social-db
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16

#TEST
%test.quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
%test.quarkus.datasource.username=sa
%test.quarkus.datasource.password=

%test.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:quarkus-social-test-db
%test.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generated=drop-and-base
%test.quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
```

User.java class

```
package io.github.dougllasfps.model;

import lombok.Data;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

}
```

UserResource.java class

```
package io.github.dougllasfps.controllers;

import io.github.dougllasfps.dtos.CreateUserRequest;
import io.github.dougllasfps.dtos.ResponseError;
import io.github.dougllasfps.model.User;
import io.github.dougllasfps.repository.UserRepository;
import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheQuery;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.Set;

@Path("/users")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private Validator validator;

    @Inject
    public UserResource(UserRepository userRepository, Validator validator) {

        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    @POST
    @Transactional
    public Response createUser(CreateUserRequest userRequest) {

        Set<ConstraintViolation<CreateUserRequest>> violentions = validator.validate(userRequest);

        if(!violentions.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseError.createFromValidation(violentions)
                                .withStatusCode(ResponseError.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY_STATUS);
        }

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(userRequest.getName());
        user.setAge(userRequest.getAge());

        userRepository.persist(user);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode()).entity(user).build();
    }
}
```

CreateUserRequest.java class

```
package io.github.dougllasfps.dtos;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Data
public class CreateUserRequest {
    @NotBlank(message = "Name is required!")
    private String name;
    @NotNull(message = "Age is required!")
    private Integer age;
}
```

UserResourceTest.java class

```
package io.github.dougllasfps.controllers;

import groovy.json.JsonBuilder;
import io.github.dougllasfps.dtos.CreateUserRequest;
import io.github.dougllasfps.model.User;
import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResource;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;

import javax.json.bind.JsonbBuilder;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

@QuarkusTest
class UserResourceTest {

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should create user successfully")
    public void createUserTest() {
        var userRequest = new CreateUserRequest();
        userRequest.setName("Fulano");
        userRequest.setAge(20);

        var response =
            given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(userRequest)
            .when()
                .post("/users")
            .then()
                .extract()
                .response();

        assertEquals(201, response.statusCode());
        assertNotNull(response.jsonPath().getString("id"));
    }
}
```

Below is the stack trace of the error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :201
Actual   :500
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:151)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.failNotEqual(AssertEquals.java:197)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:145)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:528)
    at io.github.dougllasfps.controllers.UserResourceTest.createUserTest(UserResourceTest.java:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:1002)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:816)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
    Suppressed: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:105)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:359)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:218)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:519)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:82)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:147)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler$1.run(VertxRequestHandler.java:93)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:762)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession.persist(TransactionScopedSession.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionLazyDelegator.persist(SessionLazyDelegator.java:241)
        at org.hibernate.Session_5b93bee577ae2f8d76647de04cfab36afbf52958_Synthetic_ClientProxy.persist(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.persist(AbstractJpaOperations.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.common.runtime.AbstractJpaOperations.persist(AbstractJpaOperations.java:96)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheRepositoryBase.persist(PanacheRepositoryBase.java:54)
        at io.github.dougllasfps.repository.UserRepository_ClientProxy.persist(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.dougllasfps.controllers.UserResource.createUser(UserResource.java:48)
        at io.github.dougllasfps.controllers.UserResource_Subclass.createUser$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
        at io.github.dougllasfps.controllers.UserResource_Subclass$$function$$1.apply(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:133)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.invokeInOurTx(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:104)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.doIntercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:38)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorBase.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorBase.java:58)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired.intercept(TransactionalInterceptorRequired.java:32)
        at io.quarkus.narayana.jta.runtime.interceptor.TransactionalInterceptorRequired_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:42)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:33)
        at io.github.dougllasfps.controllers.UserResource_Subclass.createUser(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:408)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:69)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.prepare(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:40)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3914)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:329)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756)
        ... 52 more
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "USERS" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into users (id, age, name) values (default, ?, ?) [42104-214]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8385)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8369)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8358)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8328)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1632)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:814)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661)
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631)
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:1044)
        at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.ConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper.java:694)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$2.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
        ... 71 more

2023-05-07 20:52:46,894 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) quarkus-social stopped in 0.061s
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58403', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I created a method in the test class to insert a record into the user entity and I expected an HttpStatus 201 and got an HttpStatus 500

What would be the reason for this error to occur?

Comment: You've pasted the irrelevant stack trace; that merely explains: The server returned 500. That's it. You want the stack trace _of the server_ which surely didn't just serve up a 500 out of the blue; there is a stack trace that explains what went wrong. Without it, it could be a million things, so there's no sensible way to try to answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error stacktrace you have the following message

```
    Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "USERS" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into users (id, age, name) values (default, ?, ?)
```

Sounds like you were able to connect to the database, but you haven't created the table `users`. If you have some init script or config to generate the schema, it's not well setup in that test

Comment: I will make an initial script to create the tables and test again. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: If the assert is not the expected one, always check the log messages to understand what is happening during the execution. `200 is not equals to 500` is just the result of executing the test, the error messages should help you to understand what was the root cause of your issue. If no message was logged, you should add them and if it is not possible you would need to use the debugger

Comment: It worked out! In the root of the project I created a 'db' folder and placed a .sql script with the commands to create the database and the table to be tested. I made a change in the application.properties file leaving only the configuration for the test bank enabled.

Comment: That's awesome. Feel free to edit the post adding those details and maybe removing some extra details that are not relevant. Maybe a title that says something about the table not being created in test. Doing that could help other members of the community in a future. Please mark the question as solved